# Como colocar o concatenar un espacio en PHP ROW

Tags: php

Tengo este código funcionando:

```
<?php
foreach ($datos as $i) {
    echo "
        <li>
          <div class=' texto_slider '>
            <p class='text-white ml-4'><img src='/$i[Icono]' class='Icono_slider'>$i[Titulo]    $i[Fecha]</p>
          </div>
          <img src='/$i[Imagen]' class='imagen_slider'></img>
        </li>";
} ?>
```

Resulta que entre `$i[Titulo]    $i[Fecha]` y fecha necesito colocar un espacio pero no puedo con `." ".` porque hay comillas dobles desde el `<li>`   ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Añade ahí el html de espacio en blanco. Algo así: `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Aunque ocupa 4 caracteres a funcionado (Muchas gracias) si alguien sabe otro método y lo puede compartir le agradeceré igual (De momento sigo)

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre ahora, que el contenido de `$i[Titulo]` y `$i[Fecha]` se muestra junto? Debería reconocer el espacio en blanco que has puesto, un espacio, si quieres más de uno quizá debas probar con `&nbsp;` como te sugiere @Jakala , uno por cada espacio que quieras.

Comment: *si alguien sabe otro método y lo puede compartir le agradeceré igual*. La mejor forma de hacer esto es vía `.css`, asignas una clase a esos elementos y luego por `.css` indicas el espaciado que quieras o lo que sea.

Comment: Aparte de `&nbsp;`, que agrega un espacio cada vez, también tienes las etiquetas `&ensp;` que agrega dos de golpe, o bien `&emsp;` que te agrega 4, así no tienes que repetir tanto el `&nbsp;`.  Comprueba que funcionen con el fuente de tu página y tu navegador destino por si acaso, pues con determinados fuentes y navegadores podrian dar problemas.

Answer (score 0):

HTML trata varios espacios en blanco contiguos como un solo espacio, [como se indica en la especificación](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html32-20180315/#sgml):

> Except within literal text (e.g. the PRE element), HTML treats
> contiguous sequences of white space characters as being equivalent to
> a single space character (ASCII decimal 32). These rules allow authors
> considerable flexibility when editing the marked-up text directly.
> Note that future revisions to HTML may allow for the interpretation of
> the horizontal tab character (ASCII decimal 9) with respect to a tab
> rule defined by an associated style sheet.

---

> Excepto dentro del texto literal (por ejemplo, el elemento `PRE`),
> HTML trata las secuencias contiguas de caracteres de espacio en blanco
> como si fueran equivalentes a un solo carácter de espacio (ASCII
> decimal 32). Estas reglas permiten a los autores una flexibilidad
> considerable al editar el texto marcado directamente. Tenga en cuenta
> que las revisiones futuras de HTML pueden permitir la interpretación
> del carácter de tabulación horizontal (ASCII decimal 9) con respecto a
> una regla de tabulación definida por una hoja de estilo asociada.

Por eso tus espacios no son reconocidos como múltiples, si quieres `N` espacios, deberás indicarlo de forma explícita, poniendo por ejemplo `N` veces el elemento `&nbsp;`

```
class='Icono_slider'>$i[Titulo]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$i[Fecha]
```

Aunque la mejor forma para aplicar estilos es mediante reglas de estilo.

Así, puedes definir una clase en tu `.css` en la que indiques los espacios que quieres. Por ejemplo:

En el código PHP:

```
class='Icono_slider'>$i[Titulo]<span class='left-tab'>$i[Fecha]</span>
```

Y en el `.css` defines una clase:

```
.left-tab {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Tendrías esto más o menos (puedes cambiar el valor `20px` por otro espacio que desees):

```css
.left-tab {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
Título<span class="left-tab">Fecha</span>
```